# Line breaks in long acronyms with the packages hyperref and acronym

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, acronyms

I am using both the `acronym` and `hyperref` packages. If I use only one of them, there's nothing wrong but if I use both, then the auto line break does not work. I want automatic line break, can someone help me please?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}  
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document}
    
%---------------------
\section{Abbreviation}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{t1}[TEST1]{This Is Test 1}
\acro{t2}[TEST2]{ThisIsTestThisIsTestThisIsTestThisIsTestThisIsTestThisIsTestThisIsTest}
\end{acronym}

%---------------------
\section{Text}
this is am example \ac{t1} this is am example this is am example this is am example this is am example this is am example this is am example this is am exampleam exampleam example \ac{t2} this is am example this is am example this is am example 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried brute force (my favorite tool): Manually break the linked text into two parts, each of which has its own hyperlink to the same place. Disadvantage: If you edit that paragraph, the break is wrong.